# Finding (2n C n) mod (1000000006)

Tags: combinations, modulo, greatest-common-divisor

I am trying to solve this problem on spoj - http://www.spoj.com/problems/POWPOW/
I have reduced it to the stage where I have to find (a ^ (exp % (M-1))) % M,(M = 1000000007) by using Fermat's little theorem. But now I face a big problem to find exp % M. We can not use inverse modulo here to find 1/(n!) mod (M-1) since gcd(n!, M-1) != 1. 
I have researched a lot on google and programming websites for this. The only thing I have found is to use chinese remainder theorem to solve these equations:
N = 1 MOD 2
N = exp MOD 500000003
and N will be the exp % (M-1)
But I am not able to understand how can we reach these equations? Is there any other way to solve this?